# logstash does not create index

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, cloud-foundry

I've setup logstash 1.5.0 with elasticsearch 1.5.1. Kibana is up and running the logstash interface via nginx.

However it seems that logstash is not creating an elastic search index.

This is what I get when I try to curl the indexes from elasticsearch:

```
[root@aoadbld00032lb ~]# curl -s http://127.0.0.1:9200/_status?pretty=true
{
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "successful" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "indices" : { }
}
```

And this is what I'm seeing in the logstash logs:

```
{:timestamp=>"2015-05-17T16:45:08.435000-0400", :message=>"Using version 0.1.x     input plugin 'tcp'. This plugin isn't well supporte
d by the community and likely has no maintainer.", :level=>:info}
{:timestamp=>"2015-05-17T16:45:08.449000-0400", :message=>"Using version 0.1.x     codec plugin 'line'. This plugin isn't well support
ed by the community and likely has no maintainer.", :level=>:info}
    {:timestamp=>"2015-05-17T16:45:08.458000-0400", :message=>"Using version     0.1.x input plugin 'udp'. This plugin isn't well supported by the community and     likely has no maintainer.", :level=>:info}
    {:timestamp=>"2015-05-17T16:45:08.462000-0400", :message=>"Using version         0.1.x codec plugin 'plain'. This plugin isn't well supported by the community and     likely has no maintainer.", :level=>:info}
{:timestamp=>"2015-05-17T16:45:08.474000-0400", :message=>"Using version 0.1.x filter plugin 'grok'. This plugin isn't well supported by the community and likely has no maintainer.", :level=>:info}
{:timestamp=>"2015-05-17T16:45:08.482000-0400", :message=>"Using version 0.1.x     filter plugin 'syslog_pri'. This plugin isn't well supported by the community and     likely has no maintainer.", :level=>:info}
    {:timestamp=>"2015-05-17T16:45:08.500000-0400", :message=>"Using version 0.1.    x filter plugin 'date'. This plugin isn't well supported by the community and likely has no maintainer.", :level=>:info}
{:timestamp=>"2015-05-17T16:45:08.510000-0400", :message=>"Using version 0.1.x     filter plugin 'mutate'. This plugin isn't well supported by the community and     likely has no maintainer.", :level=>:info}
{:timestamp=>"2015-05-17T16:45:08.808000-0400", :message=>"Using version 0.1.x     output plugin 'elasticsearch'. This plugin isn't well supported by the community     and likely has no maintainer.", :level=>:info}
{:timestamp=>"2015-05-17T16:45:09.781000-0400", :message=>"Starting tcp input     listener", :address=>"0.0.0.0:5000", :level=>:info}
{:timestamp=>"2015-05-17T16:45:09.807000-0400", :message=>"Starting UDP     listener", :address=>"0.0.0.0:5000", :level=>:info}
```

I'm thinking the output in bold might be important!

This is my logstash.conf file:

```
[root@aoadbld00032lb ~]# cat /etc/logstash/logstash.conf
input {
  tcp {
    port => 5000
    type => syslog
  }
  udp {
    port => 5000
    type => syslog
  }
}

filter {
  if [type] == "syslog" {
    grok {
          match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOG5424PRI}%{NONNEGINT:syslog5424_ver} +(?:%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:syslog5424_ts}|-) +(?:%{HOSTNAME:syslog5424_host}|-) +(?:%{NOTSPACE:syslog5424_app}|-) +(?:%{NOTSPACE:syslog5424_proc}|-) +(?:%{WORD:syslog5424_msgid}|-) +(?:%{SYSLOG5424SD:syslog5424_sd}|-|) +%{GREEDYDATA:syslog5424_msg}" }
    }
    syslog_pri { }
    date {
  match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
    }
    if !("_grokparsefailure" in [tags]) {
      mutate {
        replace => [ "@source_host", "%{syslog_hostname}" ]
        replace => [ "@message", "%{syslog_message}" ]
      }
    }
    mutate {
      remove_field => [ "syslog_hostname", "syslog_message", "syslog_timestamp" ]
    }
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {

    host => "127.0.0.1"
    embedded => false
    cluster => "optl_elasticsearch"

 }
    }
```

Can I please get some advice on how to get this logstash setup indexing in elastic search?

Comment: In Logstash 1.5, the `host` parameter to the `elasticsearch` output plugin must be an array.  Can you try `host => ["127.0.0.1"]` ? Also why don't you use the [`syslog`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-syslog.html) input plugin?

Comment: Also can you paste the relevant log from your Elasticsearch server (if any) and are you sure than you actually get data on your TCP/UDP port 5000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I followed this tutorial to set up ELK it created it index for me, may it helps you. Have a look for the config file with the generator.

http://operational.io/elk-stack-for-network-operations-reloaded/

Comment: this URL is not accessible